# "Already" in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

To answer the question "what makes you happy?" Can I include the word "already"?

"When I see how my dog sleeps with my kids it's already happiness."

Comment: Why? If you are answering that X makes you happy, 'already' doesn't come into it. If you were already happy anyway when you saw the dog and children, you can't say that the sight made you happy!

Comment: Using *already* doesn't make any sense to this US English speaker.  Is there a reason you want to use the word *already*?  We usually use it when one event happens before another event.